# Where can I find best practices documentation for Java?

Tags: java, standards

I would like to know where I can find best practices documentation for Java for:

- Coding standards
- Error management
- Logging best practices
- Unit testing
- Properties
- Data access

etc.

Comment: It's all over the internet. But prefer SUN (Oracle) sources.

Comment: A good web site to check out is http://www.java-sources.net/ You can compare libraries by category.

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265147/can-you-help-me-gather-a-java-best-practices-online-material-collection - I think the answers that will present themselves here will be very similar to the answers to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Effective Java, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)

After that, you can look at specific books for specific areas (such as unit testing). There are a *lot* of ways to do things in Java, so unlike say .NET, there is often no obvious first approach to many common problems - there are competing frameworks.

Comment: Reading that book myself now, great book, but I feel it requires that you have some experience first.

Comment: @Fredrik, quite true, but a rank beginner isn't quite at the point of Best Practices anyway.

Comment: link is dead.. new link http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683

Answer (score 2):

Beside good documentation (which you have to read, understand and keep in mind) I recommend using some static code analyzer tools which will 'inform' you 'just in time' on your porject if you violate some rules. Have a look at:

- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)

They all integrate to various IDEs and looking at their documentation (rule sets) is quite valuable.

But - they are just tools. You should always question their warnings - which in turn needs some experience.